# Customize FillingStyle in LIstPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to plot inundation at different elevations on a 3D ground surface elevation plot. The closest I have got so far has been to use `FillingStyle` as the following simple example shows:

`ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}], 
  Filling -> 0, FillingStyle -> {Blue, None}]`

[image]

But I want the water to be shown only on the ground. In other words, I want the filling operation to be done only when the surface is lower than the filling plane (z=0 in this example). Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
table = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}];

Show[ListPlot3D[table],
 ListPlot3D[table, Filling -> 0, RegionFunction -> (#3 <= 0 &), FillingStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @MathX, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.